# Check all checkBoxes inside of a checkable groupBox by checking and unchecking the GroupBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcheckbox, qgroupbox

I have a GroupBox and inside of it I have 6 checkBoxes. I want them to be checked when I check the GroupBox and unchecked when I uncheck the GroupBox, like toggling all of them.

Something like:

```
for box in self.GroupBox.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox):
    if self.GroupBox.isChecked()==True:
        box.setChecked ==True
    else:
        pixel_box.setChecked == False
```

How Can I do that?

Comment: When you create each checkbox, just add a line like this: `self.GroupBox.toggled.connect(checkbox.setChecked)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes must be made every time the `QGroupBox` changes, so it provides the toggled signal, so a slot will be connected and the changes will be made.

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#checkable-prop):

> **checkable : bool**
>
> This property holds whether the group box has a checkbox in its title
>
> If this property is true, the group box displays its title using a
>   checkbox in place of an ordinary label. If the checkbox is checked,
>   the group box's children are enabled; otherwise, they are disabled and
>   inaccessible.

From the above it is observed that the children are disabled, and this is an unexpected situation, but ours is to enable it.

From all of the above the following should be done:

```
    self.GroupBox.toggled.connect(self.onToggled)
    self.GroupBox.setCheckable(True)

def onToggled(self, on):
    for box in self.sender().findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox):
        box.setChecked(on)
        box.setEnabled(True)
```

An example that implements the above is the following:

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.GroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self)

        self.GroupBox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        for i in range(6):
            checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox("{}".format(i), self.GroupBox)
            self.GroupBox.layout().addWidget(checkbox)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.GroupBox)
        self.GroupBox.toggled.connect(self.onToggled)
        self.GroupBox.setCheckable(True)

    def onToggled(self, on):
        for box in self.sender().findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox):
            box.setChecked(on)
            box.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can not vote up, but it solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @james.rio Everyone can mark a response as correct, there is an arrow on the right side, please mark it.

Comment: @james.rio Please read the following so you can understand my suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: sorry, new here. Thanks!